# How to get multiple values from one tag

Tags: java, xml, arraylist

I have xml file like this:

```
     <newInsert>
                <!-- ONE_SVC_FLAGS -->
                <svcFlag>152</svcFlag>
                <svcFlag>153</svcFlag>
                <channelDesc>SAMPLE FOR CHANNEL1</channelDesc>
                <channelDesc>SAMPLE FOR CHANNEL2</channelDesc>
      <newInsert>
```

I was able to get one value using:

```
     for(int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node nodes = nList.item(i);
        if (nodes.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Element element = (Element) nodes;
svcFlag = element.getElementsByTagName("svcFlag").item(0).getTextContent();
channelDesc= element.getElementsByTagName("channelDesc").item(0).getTextContent();
    }
}
```

My problem is how will I get all the values under svcFlag tag and channelDesc tag:
        Expected output:

```
        svcFlag: 152
        svcFlag: 153
        channelDesc: SAMPLE FOR CHANNEL1
        channelDesc: SAMPLE FOR CHANNEL2
```

Answer (score 0):

You should post more code to get better responses but it looks like you are only assigning the first item, if you know there is two you can do this:

```
int scvflag2; // or whatever variable type used for scvflag1
String channelDesc2;

     for(int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node nodes = nList.item(i);
        if (nodes.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Element element = (Element) nodes;
svcFlag = element.getElementsByTagName("svcFlag").item(0).getTextContent();
scvFlag2 = element.getElementsByTagName("svcFlag").item(1).getTextContent();
channelDesc= element.getElementsByTagName("channelDesc").item(0).getTextContent();
channelDesc2 = element.getElementsByTagName("channelDesc").item(1).getTextContent();
    }
}
```

If you are unsure how many of each element there are you can loop through the element items and assign them accordingly.